# How do I know whether any exe file is installed by python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def tocheck():
    exe = is_program_installed("Zoom")
    print(exe)
    
tocheck()
```

I want to check the any exe file is already installed or not, tried the above code but gives none as zoom is installed in my machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `winapps` python library for that.

```
import winapps

def tocheck():
    exe = [app.name for app in winapps.search_installed('firefox')]
    print(exe)
    
tocheck()
```